# LyX: Two differently sized subfigures with a combined width of 100% columnwidth

Tags: floats, lyx, subfloats

On LyX I'm trying to create 2 subfigures (one with a square shaped graphic and one that is tall and narrow) side-by-side, such that their combined width is 100% of the column (or page).

How do I do that? I've googled for ages and couldn't figure it out.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Do they need subcaptions for eventual cross-references?

Comment: Try [this](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/FiguresSideBySide)